# Adding numbers in sheets that contain words

Tags: worksheet-function

I want to add up numbers across a row. But, these numbers also have sentences with them.

So for example, in row 2 from v-AE, I want the total of just the numbers to show up in cell AG. So the total there should be 44. Any help on how to get that total there?

[image: Picture of my sheet]

Comment: I figured it out! the formula is this...   =sum(arrayformula(value(regexextract(V2:AE2,"[1-5]+"))))

Comment: `[ v ] Answer your own question`

Answer (score 0):

Putting the below formula in the desired cell should do the trick provided the numbers are always single digit and the first character of the cell (as they are in the image). Otherwise it'll take a bit more cunning:

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(V2:AE2,1)))
```